# How to speed up development for Azure Function (with Azure queue storage and Azure table storage)

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-storage, azure-table-storage, azure-storage-queues

I am new to Azure.

I need to develop a feature using Azure storage queue that triggers Azure function and has references to data in storage table. And I have to see the result in Azure function logs.

It takes quite some time (maybe 1 minute or 2) to deploy Azure function from VSCode to Azure cloud. Besides, the corresponding logs only appear several minutes (maybe 5 minutes) after I test the feature.

Just imagine that I add one more line for logging:
I will have to wait for 10 minutes to see the result. This is really inefficient for development.

Is there any way I can speed up my development flow in the scenario above?

Answer (score 0):

You can use azure devops and setup build pipelines that builds and deploys automatically when you commit to the repo, this is normally faster than deploying directly.

As for the logs I am assuming you are referring to the logs in the monitor blade of the function or the logs in application insights which will have a lag of a few minutes but you always have the option to test your functions and use log streaming to see the logs directly in real time, or use the app insights real time view as well and see events as they happen in real time.

Comment: Real time app insight is quite useful. The one of CI/CD pipeline doesn't sound easy to build though.